# Spring boot can't find field form font-end

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, postman

I send request from Angular5 to REST API (spring boot) 
but spring boot can't find the value of key (it shows `null`),
on top image you can see the raw data that I'm sending from postman.
in spring boot I'm creating a class and field to receive data.
In controller I'm already putting the `@RequestBody`

[image]

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/barcode_option", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun editBarCodeOption(model: Model,
                request: HttpServletRequest,
                response: HttpServletResponse,
                @RequestBody barcodeForm: SKBarcodeForm): ResponseEntity<*>?{

  (barcodeService.editBarcodeOption(barcodeForm)).let { barcodeData ->
      return responseOk("ok")
   } 
   return responseBadRequest()
}
```

and the kotlin class:

```
class SKBarcodeForm {
    var id: Long? = null
    var barcodeId: String? = null
    var barcodeName: String? = null
    var barcodeBrand: String? = null
    var isHidingProfile: Boolean? = null
    var isWasteAfterUsed: Boolean? = null
    var isHaveToSeparate: Boolean? = null
}
```

thank you for help :D

Comment: Add the complete info as requested url , controller code.

Comment: already add some code hope it help

Comment: Are you using an appropriate @RestController annotation for the entire controller class where the editBarCodeOption function resides?

Comment: your 2nd screenshot shows a different class named SKBarcodeOptionForm instead of SKBarcodeForm ? are you hitting the correct endpoint from postman ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the prefix 'is' from your boolean properties.

Comment: wow it's worked, how did you know that ?. cause i used to use this prefix and never found problem like this. by the way thank you so much bro